# Jekyll Scholar 7.1.3 / Jekyll 4.3.3 issue with Ruby 3.3.0 - Liquid Exception: undefined method `convert!'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I am revisiting a static website I built a few years ago with Jekyll, and having trouble compiling the source locally to then send to my github pages website. I am not technically adept so please forgive any mistakes in the below.

It seems there is a new issue with creating bibliographies for github pages using Jekyll Scholar that did not exist with prior versions of Ruby - Would love any guidance on fixes.

My static page calls:

```
{% bibliography %}
```

Which should lead to one bibliography element generated from the dummy .bib file I have put in (as per the workflow in the [relevant readme](https://github.com/inukshuk/jekyll-scholar)) - however, I get the following error:

```
  Liquid Exception: undefined method `convert!' for an instance of String in publications/index.html

C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bibtex-ruby-6.0.0/lib/bibtex/names.rb:104:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Names>': undefined method `convert!' for an instance of String (NoMethodError)

        tokens.each { |t| t.send(method_id, *arguments) }
                           ^^^^^
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bibtex-ruby-6.0.0/lib/bibtex/names.rb:104:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bibtex-ruby-6.0.0/lib/bibtex/names.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Names>'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bibtex-ruby-6.0.0/lib/bibtex/value.rb:271:in `convert'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/utilities.rb:576:in `block in liquidify'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/utilities.rb:575:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/utilities.rb:575:in `liquidify'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/utilities.rb:541:in `reference_data'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/utilities.rb:526:in `bibliography_tag'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/tags/bibliography.rb:62:in `block in render_items'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/tags/bibliography.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/tags/bibliography.rb:61:in `each_with_index'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/tags/bibliography.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/tags/bibliography.rb:61:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/tags/bibliography.rb:61:in `render_items'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar/tags/bibliography.rb:27:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/liquid-4.0.4/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:103:in `render_node_to_output'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/liquid-4.0.4/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:91:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/liquid-4.0.4/lib/liquid/template.rb:206:in `block in render'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/liquid-4.0.4/lib/liquid/template.rb:240:in `with_profiling'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/liquid-4.0.4/lib/liquid/template.rb:205:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/liquid-4.0.4/lib/liquid/template.rb:218:in `render!'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in render!'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:59:in `measure_counts'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in render!'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:63:in `measure_bytes'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:37:in `block in render!'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:70:in `measure_time'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:36:in `render!'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:129:in `render_liquid'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:80:in `render_document'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:63:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:572:in `render_regenerated'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:564:in `block in render_pages'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:563:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:563:in `render_pages'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:211:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:80:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `<main>'
```

For reference, here is my Gemfile:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.8.6)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    base64 (0.2.0)
    bibtex-ruby (6.0.0)
      latex-decode (~> 0.0)
    bigdecimal (3.1.5)
    citeproc (1.0.10)
      namae (~> 1.0)
    citeproc-ruby (1.1.14)
      citeproc (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      csl (~> 1.6)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)
    csl (1.6.0)
      namae (~> 1.0)
      rexml
    csl-styles (1.0.1.11)
      csl (~> 1.0)
    csv (3.2.8)
    em-websocket (0.5.3)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    ffi (1.16.3)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    google-protobuf (3.25.1)
    http_parser.rb (0.8.0)
    i18n (1.14.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jekyll (4.3.3)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      i18n (~> 1.0)
      jekyll-sass-converter (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 2.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.3, >= 2.3.1)
      kramdown-parser-gfm (~> 1.0)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (>= 0.3.6, < 0.5)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      terminal-table (>= 1.8, < 4.0)
      webrick (~> 1.7)
    jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
    jekyll-sass-converter (3.0.0)
      sass-embedded (~> 1.54)
    jekyll-scholar (7.1.3)
      bibtex-ruby (~> 6.0)
      citeproc-ruby (~> 1.0)
      csl-styles (~> 1.0)
      jekyll (~> 4.0)
    jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    json (2.7.1)
    kramdown (2.4.0)
      rexml
    kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.0)
    latex-decode (0.4.0)
    liquid (4.0.4)
    listen (3.8.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    mercenary (0.4.0)
    namae (1.1.1)
    observer (0.1.2)
    pathutil (0.16.2)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    public_suffix (5.0.4)
    racc (1.7.3)
    rack (2.2.8)
    rackup (1.0.0)
      rack (< 3)
      webrick
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rexml (3.2.6)
    rouge (4.2.0)
    safe_yaml (1.0.5)
    sass-embedded (1.69.5-x64-mingw-ucrt)
      google-protobuf (~> 3.23)
    terminal-table (3.0.2)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.1.1, < 3)
    unicode-display_width (2.5.0)
    webrick (1.8.1)

PLATFORMS
  x64-mingw-ucrt

DEPENDENCIES
  base64
  bigdecimal
  csv
  jekyll-paginate
  jekyll-scholar
  json
  liquid
  observer
  racc
  rack (~> 2.0)
  rackup

BUNDLED WITH
   2.5.3
```

Now, it seems that in the [relevant file from bibtex-ruby](https://github.com/inukshuk/bibtex-ruby/blob/master/lib/bibtex/names.rb), the method "convert!" is indeed used before it is defined (Line 102 vs 280) - is this what is leading to the current issue?

I saw some people advocating going back to [Ruby 2.7 in some prior threads for similar, but not identical, issues](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/9233). However, Ruby 2.7 is no longer supported, so I'd like to see if there are better fixes.